# Why does bitcoin mining take so long?

Tags: difficulty, block-interval

I was wondering that a block (Here's a [Block #506398](https://blockchain.info/block/00000000000000000008b26b9ddc6bf554f58957eeba185d0a20e5b4deed3c41))

It's nonce is 1,229,291,212 (A little over a billion), Then why does it take so long to mine a block because my system alone can do about 500 GH/s (500,000,000,000 Hashs per second), Which is very little in comparison to what an ASICs can do.

Then why does it take so long to mine a Block??

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Your system can not do 500GH/s.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/855/5406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nonce value does not itself indicate all tries. The resolution of Nonce is only 4 bytes. Every time Nonce gets up to 4,294,967,295(10) it resets and starts again from zero, updating the extraNonce and continuing.

> http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm
>   'Whenever Nonce overflows (which it does frequently), the extraNonce portion of the generation transaction is incremented, which changes the Merkle root.'

Answer (score 0):

The entire purpose of proof-of-work mining is to force participants to spin their wheels doing busywork.  It takes about 10 minutes to mine a block because the difficulty automatically changes so that it *always* takes about 10 minutes to mine a block.  When more hashing power is added to the network, the difficulty increases to accommodate.  The time it takes to mine a block is intentionally set to 10 minutes.

You should read [What exactly is Mining?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/148/24974) for clarification.

Comment: I Understand what mining is, however what I don't Understand is 1 Billion Nonce should take 1/5 th of a second for an average computer to mine, then why 10 minutes

Comment: Because that nonce probably only worked after rearranging the transactions several times.

Comment: There's two nonces, the OP is only looking at the first.