# bitcoin block time after halving?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, block

I would like to know why the bitcoin block time is taking longer than 10 minutes, I know that bitcoin halving had decrease reward and increase difficulty but according what I read the blockchain itself will regulate the block time by adjusting difficulty to create a new block in order to have the same block time as first block was ever mined.Now block time are taking even hours what is it ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What keeps the average block time at 10 minutes?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/855/what-keeps-the-average-block-time-at-10-minutes)

Comment: thanks for the response, because of halving and difficulty increasing, the time for block is changing recently an even will continue increasing, that's the summary but because  halving miners are increasing by themselves the fees and controlling what to mine, I don't agree.

Answer (score 3):

After halving, the reward goes down by 1/2. Some miners may find it unprofitable to mine and thus shut down their mining operation. However, the network difficulty remains the same until the next difficulty adjustment, which is every 2016 blocks (14 days approximately). Thus, the block time will increase to > 10 mins per block until the next difficulty adjustment.